# only convert certain rows with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame`. I am trying to manipulate a column to show month count. If a record is `01m` then make it 1. Otherwise if it is a `01y`, times 1 x 12 to make 12. However sometimes I do have a field called `_variable_value` which I would like to leave as is. (ignore)

The current `dataframe` looks like this:

```
      institution_short_name            product_name             Term  term
0                        One                Standard       _01y_value  4.85
1                        One                Standard       _02y_value  5.15
2                        One                Standard       _03y_value  5.49
3                        One                Standard       _04y_value  5.89
4                        One                Standard       _05y_value  6.09
5                        One                Standard       _06m_value  4.99
6                        One                Standard       _18m_value  5.15
7                        One                Standard  _variable_value  5.79
```

I currently get an error as it is trying to convert `'va'` to int which is not possible.

```
df['Time'] = np.where(df['Time'].str.contains("y"), df['Time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:3]).astype(int).apply(lambda x: x*12), df['Time'].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:3]).astype(int))
```

This is my expected output:

```
      institution_short_name            product_name             Term  term
0                        One                Standard               12  4.85
1                        One                Standard               24  5.15
2                        One                Standard               36  5.49
3                        One                Standard               48  5.89
4                        One                Standard               60  6.09
5                        One                Standard                6  4.99
6                        One                Standard               18  5.15
7                        One                Standard  _variable_value  5.79
```

Comment: Kindly provide a sample df in pandas code `pd.DataFrame()` format. We shouldn't need to re-create the data.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you could copy and paste them in!

Comment: now you've removed the lines, I can do copy paste now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it with `str.replace` and regular expression:

```
df['Time'] = df.Time.str.replace(
    r"_(\d{2})([ym]).*", 
    lambda m: str(int(m.group(1)) * (12 if m.group(2) == "y" else 1))
)

df

#  institution_short_name product_name             Time  term
#0                    One     Standard               12  4.85
#1                    One     Standard               24  5.15
#2                    One     Standard               36  5.49
#3                    One     Standard               48  5.89
#4                    One     Standard               60  6.09
#5                    One     Standard                6  4.99
#6                    One     Standard               18  5.15
#7                    One     Standard  _variable_value  5.79
```

`_(\d{2})([ym]).*` matches strings that start with `_ + two digits + y or m`, and captures the digits and units into two different groups; based on the unit, you can modify the matched numeric values as needed by referring to the groups in a lambda function; Cases such as `_variable_value` that don't match the pattern are ignored.